# How to enable logs or figure out which parsers are being called in Apache Tika

Tags: apache-tika

I want to know whats  going on  in the call in

```
java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar -j -v banana-gif.wbmp
```

I have tried to use all possible image and auto parsers  but it does not match the output received from this command.

```
 { "Chroma BlackIsZero":"true",
"Content-Length":63552,
"Content-Type":"image/vnd.wap.wbmp",
"Dimension ImageOrientation":"Normal",
"height":534,
"resourceName":"banana-gif.wbmp",
"tiff:ImageLength":534,
"tiff:ImageWidth":950,
"width":950 }
```

I want to enable full logs when running this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one - work out what kind of file Tika thinks it is. You can either get that from the metadata if you're already passing it, or from the Tika App using the detect option

```
$ java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar --detect wireframe.pdf 
application/pdf
```

Next up, you need to get the list of all the parsers that the Tika App version you're using knows about, along with the mime types that they handle:

```
$ java -jar tika-app-1.5.jar --list-parser-details | grep -B 2 -A 2 application/pdf
  application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart
org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser
  application/pdf
org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.CompressorParser
  application/x-bzip
```

From that, we see that a PDF file would be handled by `org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser`

For your specific case of `image/vnd.wap.wbmp` and Tika 1.5, we see that the parser being used is `org.apache.tika.parser.image.ImageParser`

(Note - all of this applies to using the Tika-App executable jar, where you can't change this. If you were using Tika from your own Java code you'd have more options available, but where you also have to make sure you include all the dependency jars for it to work properly!)

Comment: I am still facing issues with wbmp file. In the command like the extraction is working fine but when passed via a input  stream it is  not able to recognise the type and thus  defaulting to application/octet-stream.  forcing it to pickup image parser too does not help as when it gets into tika 1.5 it overrides all  the  type passed extracts the type as application/octet-stream and then passes it to DefaultParser and then it gets into EmptyParser thus not able to extract any metadata

Comment: Why not pass the filename along with the stream, so Tika is better able to identify it?

Comment: I debugged the Apache  tika and Tika does not even look at the file name it extracts the  Mimetype and then applies the logic of hiearchy of files to map the parser. I am kind of getting convinced  that  I  will have to work on how the file is being handled by the browser which  is sending the input  stream.

Comment: I can assure you that if you give Tika the filename in the correct way, Tika will use it. However, without any code in your question it isn't possible to work out what you've done wrong...